# Subset df to keep only cols where row value matches X

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, subset

I have a df that consists of a single row. To understand why I have a dataframe of just one row, read on, if not, skip ahead to the TLDR;.

**Background**
This is part of a larger clustering project that I'm using to help me understand where changes are occurring in a dataset from week to week. I've manipulated my data so that each column is a binary field indicating whether the data in that column changed from the last time I pulled the dataset from our system.

I've run k-medoids clustering (PAM), determined the medoids (the middle representative observation) for my clusters, and now I'm examining them. There is only one medoid per cluster (which is as expected), so when I extract them, I end up looking at dataframes that are just a single row with 70+ columns.

The medoid observation is representative of all the other observations in its cluster, so it's important that I can distill what makes the medoid from Cluster A different from the medoid in Cluster B.  But, since I have so many columns, this is hard to do visually.

What I want to do is take these 70+ columns and filter them so that I only see columns where the value changed from one week to the next, aka, all the columns that have a value of "Change".

This seems really straightforward, like something I should be able to easily do with base R or dplyr, but for some reason I'm really struggling with the syntax and I feel like an idiot.

**TLDR;**

My sample data is a single row df that looks something like this. I just want columns where the row value says "Change".

```
df<-data.frame(ID = 12345, 
               ORDER_STATUS = 'Change',
               ORDER_DATE = 'Change',
               PRODUCT = 'Same',
               CUSTOMER = 'Same',
               STATE = 'Same')
```

I have tried numerous things, but what seems to be the closest would be something along these lines:

`filtered_df <- df %>% filter(select(everything()) == 'Change')`

OR:

```
col_list <- colnames(df)

filter_df <- df %>% filter(if_any(all_of(col_list), ~. == 'Change'))
```

OR using base R:

`filtered_df <- df[,df[1,1:6]=="Change"]`

But those aren't working for various reasons :(

I am hoping to see something like this:

```
> filtered_df

   ID         ORDER_STATUS ORDER_DATE 
1 12345       Change       Change
```

or even without the ID would be fine, since I'll know which observation I'm looking at already:

```
 ORDER_STATUS ORDER_DATE 
 Change       Change
```

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll be ready with a facepalm if it's something super obvious.

**Edit**
Per comments, I was told that `filtered_df <- df[,df[1,1:6]=="Change"]` is giving the right answer. When I run that with my real data, I get the error:

Error in `df[, df[1, 1:71] == "Change"]`:
! Can't subset columns with `df[1, 1:71] == "Change"`.
✖ Subscript `df[1, 1:71] == "Change"` must be a simple vector, not a matrix.
Backtrace:

1. df[, df[1, 1:71] == "Change"]
2. rlang::cnd_signal(x)

Comment: `df[,df[1,1:6]=="Change"]` seems to give the correct output. For this one, can you show the error message/output if it's not working for you?

Comment: Hmm @benson23
you're right! In my real data though, I get this error: Error in df[, df[1, 1:71] == "Change"] :
✖ Subscript `df[1, 1:71] == "Change"` must be a simple vector, not a matrix.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover yes I checked after they posted and I saw that this should work already. When I use my real data  though, I'm getting an error.

Comment: It might be related to data structure problem, are you sure your real data are of class data.frame? Can you share a subset of your real data using `dput(df)` so that we can be sure?

Comment: BTW the `dplyr` alternative for this problem is quite simple, just couple `select` with `where`

Comment: @benson23 unfortunately, I can't share my real data b/c it's work-related. But that has to be the answer. When I do class(df), it shows that it's a df, but also a "tbl_df" and  "tbl". I'll try playing with the structure and see if that does it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. That's why it's not working, you need to use `as.data.frame` to change the tibble back to a base data.frame first. Indexing a tibble works differently compared with base data.frame

Comment: Thank you! Cue facepalm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use argument `drop = TRUE` when extracting from the logical matrix.

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 12345, 
                 ORDER_STATUS = 'Change',
                 ORDER_DATE = 'Change',
                 PRODUCT = 'Same',
                 CUSTOMER = 'Same',
                 STATE = 'Same')
# returns a matrix
(df == "Change")
#>         ID ORDER_STATUS ORDER_DATE PRODUCT CUSTOMER STATE
#> [1,] FALSE         TRUE       TRUE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE

(df == "Change") |> class()
#> [1] "matrix" "array"

# returns a named logical vector
(df == "Change")[1, , drop = TRUE]
#>           ID ORDER_STATUS   ORDER_DATE      PRODUCT     CUSTOMER        STATE 
#>        FALSE         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE

(df == "Change")[1, , drop = TRUE] |> class()
#> [1] "logical"

# use the logical vector to subset the columns
df[, (df == "Change")[, , drop = TRUE]]
#>   ORDER_STATUS ORDER_DATE
#> 1       Change     Change
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

After comments from @benson23, the solution ends up being that my df in real life was class "tbl_df", "tbl" and "data.frame".

I needed to convert it to a data frame and do the following with my real data:

```
df<-as.data.frame(df)

df[,df[1,1:ncol(df)]=="Change"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wtih dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> select(c(ID, where(\(x) x=='Change')))

     ID ORDER_STATUS ORDER_DATE
1 12345       Change     Change
```

This is likely going to fail with multi-line data.frames, because the equality comparison would then output a logical vector, whereas the anonymous function inside `where` can only accept logical scalars.
Depending on the desired logic, we may include an aditional function like `all` or `any`:

```
df |> select(c(ID, where(\(x) any(x == 'Change'))))
```